# Magento custom product type Class 'Zend_Log' not found in

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to make custom product type in magento 1.8 , everything works fine but when adding the product to cart  i get this error :  Class 'Zend_Log' not found in .../Dmx/Plate/Model/Product/Type/Plate.php on line 23.

```
class Dmx_Plate_Model_Product_Type_Plate extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract{

    protected $_isComposite = false;
    protected $_canConfigure = true;

    protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode){
        $preparedProduct = parent::_prepareProduct($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
        $preparedProduct = $preparedProduct[0];
        $preparedProduct->setPrice(10);

        return array($preparedProduct);
    }

    public function hasRequiredOptions($product = null){
        return true;
    }

    public function hasOptions($product){
        return true;
    }
}
```

So i can't figure it out what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Donot do anything in Plate.php and please remove the price code from here

```
<?php
class Dmx_Plate_Model_Product_Type_Plate extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract{

    protected $_isComposite = false;
    protected $_canConfigure = true;

    protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode){
                return parent::_prepareProduct($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
    }

    public function hasRequiredOptions($product = null){
        return true;
    }

    public function hasOptions($product){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Call price.php for that model

```
<?php 
class Dmx_Plate_Model_Product_Type_Plate_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{
     protected function _applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice)
    {
            $basePrice = $finalPrice;
            //$finalPrice=785;
             /*
            if($product->getCustomOption('card_amount'))
            {
             $giftcartprice=$product->getCustomOption('card_amount')->getValue();
            $curretCurrency=Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
            $baseCurrency=Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency();
            $cardCurrency = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load($curretCurrency);
            $currentRadio=$baseCurrency->getRate($cardCurrency);
            $finalGiftcartdPrice=$giftcartprice;
            if($currentRadio)
            {   
            $finalGiftcartdPrice=$giftcartprice/$currentRadio;
            }
           foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                if ($option = $product->getOptionById($optionId)) {
                    $confItemOption = $product->getCustomOption('option_'.$option->getId());

                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setConfigurationItemOption($confItemOption);
                    $finalPrice += $group->getOptionPrice($confItemOption->getValue(), $basePrice);
                }
            }
            $finalPrice+=$finalGiftcartdPrice;
            }*/
        return $finalPrice;
        return 10;
    }

}
?>
```

need to add price model file for plate product `<price_model>plate/product_type_plate_price</price_model>`

Should  be add editing config.xml

```
<catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <plate translate="label" module="plate">
                    <label>Plate</label>
                    <model>plate/product_type_plate</model>
                    <price_model>plate/product_type_plate_price</price_model>
                     <index_data_retreiver>plate/catalogindex_data_plate</index_data_retreiver>  
                    <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                     <composite>0</composite>
                </plate>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
```